# Any difference between result set from a view vs a physical table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am dealing with a software vendor who insisted that view is behaving differently from a physical table. The system is having error and they blame us for using view than the physical table.

Is this true? I'm using SQL2008R2. It will be helpful also if there is a strong reference to proof it. Thank you.

Comment: maybe the software vendor can show you the evidence :-)

Comment: Good one, Leo.. :) Sadly we are dealing with a difficult vendor who insisted that it did not work because we are using view not table. Finally we inserted the result set to a table. The application still generates error so definitely it's not due to view/table difference.

Answer (score 0):

It might be behaving differently if the view makes an aggregation or if the view combines several tables or does anything else apart from just showing the original table.

If your view is created as

```
create view my_view as select * from my_table
```

there is no difference in behaiviour or data

But if your view is created for example as

```
create view my_view as select * from my_table inner join other_table on ...
```

there might be differences because of potencial data loose in the join.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand your point on the potential data loose. What I mean is the technical difference between result set from a table and a view. If I query directly on the Management Studio, I can see the data. But when displayed in the system, it generates error. The vendor insist because the result set comes from view rather than table.

Answer (score 0):

The bytes returned to the application are the same irrespective of what internal structure SQL Server used to obtain them.